# How to unit test gRPC asynchronous C++ client functions with google test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, grpc, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to write unit tests for my C++ gRPC client, using google test. I'm using both synchronous and asynchronous rpc's, and I can't figure out how to use mock'ed version of asynchronous ones.

In my .proto file I have:

```
rpc foo(EmptyMessage) returns (FooReply) {}
```

From this `protoc` has generated mock stub with both synchronous and asynchronous calls:

```
  MOCK_METHOD3(foo, ::grpc::Status(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const ::EmptyMessage& request, ::FooReply* response));
  MOCK_METHOD3(AsyncfooRaw, ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReaderInterface< ::FooReply>*(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const ::EmptyMessage& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq));
```

I can succesfully mock synchronous calls with:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mockStub, foo).Times (1).WillOnce ([] (grpc::ClientContext *, const ::EmptyMessage &, ::FooReply *repl) {
        // I can set desired values to 'repl' here
        return grpc::Status::OK;
    });
```

**Question: how can I use the mock'ed asynchronous foo() rpc?**

I have tried for example:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mockStub, AsyncfooRaw).Times (1).WillOnce ([] (::grpc::ClientContext* context, const ::EmptyMessage& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq)
                                                                           -> grpc_impl::ClientAsyncResponseReaderInterface<::FooReply>* {
   ...
```

which compiles, but I get:

```
GMOCK WARNING:
Uninteresting mock function call - returning default value.
    Function call: AsyncfooRaw
```

which to my understanding means gmock does not find the handler for AsyncfooRaw I'm trying to provide.

Comment: "Uninteresting mock function call - returning default value." means that the call was performed, but might be the arguments didn't match. Use any matcher ('testing::_') to test if this helps maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, gRPC doesn't offer a way to create mocks for the async API.  There were some historical constraints that made this infeasible when the async API was first developed, and as a result, the API wasn't really designed to support this.

We might want to look at supporting this for the new [callback-based API](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/L67-cpp-callback-api.md), which is intended to replace the async API.  Feel free to file a feature request for this.  However, it will require some investigation, and I'm not sure how quickly we'll be able to get to it.

In the interim, the best work-around is to create a server implementation and add your mocks there, rather than mocking the client API directly.